# Extracting from a function in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, integer, extract, store

I have the following data types

```
type Store = Loc -> Z
type Loc = Z
type Z = Integer
```

where the basic idea is that a Store maps a Location to an integer. And each Location is represented by its own integer identifier.

Now elsewhere in the task I have a Store (Loc -> Z) which I need to extract the integer from. So I need a function that takes in a store and returns just the Z part.

```
funExtract :: Store -> Z
funExtract sto = ???
```

For the life of me everything I've tried throws some sort of error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your `Store` type is `Integer -> Integer` so `funExtract` has type `(Integer -> Integer) -> Integer`. There is no `Z` part to extract unless you pass the location you want.

Comment: There isn't anything actually stored in your `sto` argument, the `Store` type just acts as a lookup for a given `Loc`.  What you might want is a function `extract :: Store -> Loc -> Z`; `extract store loc = store loc`.

Comment: As others have said you can't extract the Integer from a Store, unless you provide it a Location. Is it possible that instead of a mapping, what you really wanted was something like `type Store = (Loc, Z)` ?

Comment: @bheklilr Or, since `Store` is a function and "extracting" a value is function application, `extract = ($)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh yes, imitate a store by building a function.  A good exercise common in programming languages classes.  You'll want two functions, one to build a store and one to extract values.  To build a store you want to take the original store, the element to insert, and the location:

```
type Store = Loc -> Z
type Loc = Z
type Z = Integer

extend :: Loc -> Z -> Store -> Store
extend loc val st = \look ->
  if look == loc then val else st look
```

In `extend` we just define a function that returns the value if you pass it the matching location.  If the location doesn't match then maybe the location was defined in the original store, so we apply that store to the lookup.

Now for implementing lookup:

```
funExtract :: Store -> Loc -> Z
funExtract sto loc = sto loc
```

Notice that?  What you proposed is to implement a storage system as a function so lookup is just function application.  Since we aren't returning something with an `empty` value, like a `Maybe a` type, we'll need to do something drastic if the location isn't in our store.  Let's make lookup on empty store an error:

```
emptyStore :: Store
emptyStore loc = error $ "Can not find location " ++ show loc ++ "."
```

Below I play with this construct a little in GHCi.

```
*Main> let sto = extend 1 31337 (extend 0 1337 emptyStore)
*Main> sto 0
1337
*Main> sto 1
31337
*Main> sto 2
*** Exception: Can not find location 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Store` is a type of function wich takes a location and maps it to an integer. To implement task you should either store all locations inside `funExtract` or to use an external storage like `Data.Map`. Here is how to do this.

```
import qualified Data.Map as DM

type Store = Loc -> Z
type Loc   = Z
type Z     = Integer

-- First way --

funExtract :: Store
funExtract 1 = 2
funExtract 2 = 9
-- here could be more values:          --
--   for each new values a new pattern --
funExtract 108 = 17

{- This solution doesn't allow to add new locations
   at the runtime. Look at Thomas's answer to understand
   how to do this with function as a container. Or look
   at the second way:                                    -}

-- Second way --

-- To add new location, add it to locStorage using
-- functions from Data.Map.
locStorage :: DM.Map Loc Z
locStorage = DM.fromList [(1, 2), (2, 9), {- ... -} (108, 17)]

-- `funExtract` becomes just a query
funExtract' :: Store
funExtract' = (DM.!) locStorage
```